# Backing up a VM before deleting

Tags: azure, backup, azure-virtual-machine

We have one Linux and one Windows VM that we no longer have a need for. Before we delete the VM, we would like to back it in case we need to go back to it. What is the best way to do this?

Thank you!
Sanjeev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best method is to use the Azure Backup Service
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-overview